# Spring Bean tag error

Tags: spring, spring-security

Could some please let me know what things I am missing here. I m getting the below exception

```
 Line 76 in XML document from file [C:\S2\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\proj_name\WEB-INF\classes\spring\test-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is 
 org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content 
 was found starting with element 'bean'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":description, 
  "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":meta,            
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":constructor-arg,      "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":property, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":qualifier, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":lookup-method, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":replaced-method,     WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"]}' is expected.
```

And I have my test-context.xml as below.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">

<bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.test.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint">
```

Could anybody please let me know why I am missing here . i have spring 3.0.5 Spring jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing surrounding `<beans>` `</beans>` tags:

```
<beans>
   <bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.test.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint">
<beans>
```

This is what the error message wants to tell you...

> Invalid content was found starting with element 'bean'.

"The bean tag is not allowed here"

> One of [..] beans, [..] is expected

The only valid tags here are "beans", etc.

Comment: Thank you so much you saved my time.

Answer (score 0):

Add `<beans:beans/>` to your config xml.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch.xsd">

  <beans:beans id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="com.test.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint"/>

</beans:beans>
```

In your xml you have opened `<bean>` tag but not closed. 
`<beans xmlns....>`
where is `</beans>` and same for `restAuthenticationEntryPoint` 
so you are getting that exception.